# Обновление маски textview cornerRadius

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, textview

В функции `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` у меня грузится ячейка с text view. Должно быть что то типа такого:

[image: Как нужно]

Код отрисовки следующий:

```
    UIRectCorner rectCorner = UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight;
    
    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.viewMessage.bounds
                                     byRoundingCorners:rectCorner
                                           cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];
    
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    
    cell.viewMessage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.viewMessage.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Проблема в том, что после загрузки таблицы Вид следующий:

[image: Как есть]

Но стоит пролистать таблицу вниз и снов вверх то, она отрисовывается как нужно. Как сделать так, чтобы сразу рисовалась как надо?

P.S. Размер TextView динамический меняется в зависимости от текста.

Comment: Размер ячейки меняется динамически, или только меняется размер UITextView?

Comment: @Fidel Меняется как размер ячейки, так и UITextView

Comment: У вас, @Northex,  UITextView лежит на contentView ячейки, так я предпологаю, а под этим UITextView будет еще что то, типа времени или еще чего то?

Comment: @Fidel Да в ячейке  contentView в нем лежит еще один UView в котором уже находится  UItextView. Оранжевый фон это и есть Uiview

Comment: смотрите я совсем чуть чуть дополнил ваш код, я за субкласил ячейку(UITableViewCell), внутри нее я создал метод [метод](http://pastebin.com/VDc39Wg4) и вызываю его `[cell LoadBubbleTextView:@"Text text text"
                       Frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, Width, Height)];` Будут проблемы, пишите :)

Comment: @Fidel а width и height откуда брать?

Comment: width и height это две переменные типа `CGFloat`, которым вы можете задать размер своего `UIView`, на котором лежит `UITextField`

Comment: а если округление убрать, то все работает как надо?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko если убрать то да. если заменить код, что выше на:

    /*    CALayer *btnLayer = [cell.viewMessage layer];
        
        [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        
        [btnLayer setCornerRadius:20.0f];

То все супер, сразу отрисовывает , но закруглены все! а надо все кроме нижнего правого угла

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Здесь проблема в том что в момент создания маски, маска берет изначальный размер `cell.viewMessage`, то есть не отрисованного юай элемента. Что бы обойти проблему, надо давать маску после того как правильный фрэйм `viewMessage` был присвоен. Попробуйте этот же код перенести на `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` метод делегата. Или же вообще создать кастомную ячейку, и рисовать бублик на `layoutSubviews` метод.

П.С.: Я считаю этот метод отрисовки бубликов немножко не правильным, так как он может привести к тормозам (жрет много памяти). Лучше использовать рисунки, и их расширять под размер текста, используя метод `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` `UIImage`.